# Inequality involving exponential function

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function

It is trivial to show that $$\sqrt {1+2x} < e^x, \quad \text{for}\,  x>0$$
Is it true the stronger inequality 
$$\sqrt {1+\frac{8x}{4-x}} < e^x, \quad \text{for}\,  x>0?$$

Comment: Look at what happens when $x \rightarrow 4$ from below

Comment: Thank you Simon. It was stupid to ask about all the positive reals. But is it true at least on the interval $(0,a)$ for some $a>0$ ?

Comment: The Taylor series to second order seem to imply that this is true.

Comment: Any more details amcalde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ge 0$ then $1+x+\frac12x^2\le e^x$ because the LHS is a truncation of the power series for $e^x$ and the missing terms are positive.  Thus if $x\in[0,3]$ then
$$ 4+7x \le 4+7x+2x^2(3-x)
= (4-x)(1+2x+2x^2)
\le (4-x)e^{2x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For some $a<4$ this appears to be true.

Comment: I get that the crossover point is about $3.98905$ give or take. It's a solution to a transcendental equation.